# jQuery Ajax returns 500 internal server error on live server, fine on localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table which is filled from a database. The user can delete one row by clicking the delete button next to it. After the click the row fades away. This works on my localhost but on the live server I get a 500 Internal server error.

The strange thing is, there is a pretty much similar function tied to another element and that works fine. I simply copied the original one that was not written by me. I just wonder why on the live server the original works and my identical code does not.

Here is the my code:

```
$K2('.deleteNakladyButton').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if (confirm(K2Language[3])) {
    var element = $K2(this).parent().parent();
    var url = $K2(this).attr('href');
    $K2.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: 'get',
     success: function(){
       $K2(element).fadeOut('fast', function(){
         $K2(element).remove();
       });
     }
   });
 }
});
```

The original is different in the name of the class that it is triggered by. The original says `.deleteAttachmentsButton`.

This function is not crucial to the site but it would add a little bit more comfort for my client.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: A 500 internal server error should indicate to you that something is happening wrong on the server.

Comment: I know, but why is the original code working and my own is not since they are identical.

Comment: What is your url? Are you using `php` or `asp.net`? I have ran into this problem before. It turned out to be related to using the packaged server with Microsoft Visual Web Developer vs using IIS (Express). Once I changed over to IIS (Express), I was able to mimic a production server locally.

Comment: @Vojtech, How should we know?  You haven't posted any server-side code!

Comment: I am just a guy who makes a plugin for one site. I have no access to the server :/

Comment: There isn't much you can do differently.  It's a straightforward AJAX call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that there are (at least) 2 possible reasons for this. As said before, 500 internal server error indicates that the call to the server succeed, but the server didn't know how to handle the request.

1. See that the code on the server knows what to do with the parameters sent by ajax.
2. Check that the var 'url' holds the right url.

Comment: Stupid me! The url was indeed not correct. By getting it right now it works like a charm! Thank you!